# How do we connect 2 FSR sensors to an Arduino Mega?

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors

One can connect an FSR sensor (a [force-sensitive resistor](https://learn.adafruit.com/force-sensitive-resistor-fsr/overview)) to an Arduino via 5V, Gnd,  and A0 port (as below, according to [an adafruit.com page](https://learn.adafruit.com/force-sensitive-resistor-fsr/using-an-fsr)), but how will it work for two of them instead of one?

[image: FSR circuit]

Answer (score 1):

Attach the second FSR mostly the same as the first, but connect the second analog voltage to A1 instead of to A0.

You can use several copies of  the circuit (below left) with each circuit's analog voltage going to a different analog-converter input (A0, A1, A2, ...). 
[image: circuit + breadboard + avrisp pinout]

To connect up multiple 5V and ground connections, you can:

•  use almost any popular shield
•  use breadboards like those illustrated above
•  cut and solder Dupont cables to add extra pins or sockets in or out (for example, cut two M-F Duponts in half, and connect both F halves to one M half)
•  connect to the extra 5V and Gnd pins on Uno or Mega boards.  (On a Mega, besides 5V and Gnd pins on programming headers, there are two 5V sockets next to 22 and 23, and two Gnds next to 52 and 53.)

The diagrams above right show the location of the 5V pins on the programming headers found on the Uno.  Most Arduino boards have at least one AVRISP header like that.

Comment: What about the Ground pin and the 5V? there only 1 5V

Comment: @user19846 see edit